# OpenMP does not use all processors

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a program that uses OpenMP for loop parallelization. On development workstation with single CPU quad core it uses all cores. On server that has 2 CPU and 10 cores each the program only uses 1 CPU. Is there a way to force OpenMP to use both processors?

Comment: Are you setting OMP_NUM_THREADS? Please provide hardware and software details.

Comment: If these CPUs have different memory caches, then it's possible that you can't program them using only OpenMP, but rather MPI for the distributed memory parallelism (across the CPUs), and OpenMP for the shared memory paralellism (across the cores/CPU). We would need more info to discover if this is the case.

Comment: `omp_get_num_procs()` should output the number of available processors on the device wether the program uses them or not.  If this indeed returns 2, try setting the number of threads so that you can occupy them. Don't forget about hyperthreading as well

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll what platform today supports cache coherent processors without coherence between sockets? I know of no such hardware.

Comment: @Jeff Until proven otherwise, I'm operating under the assumption that OP's understanding of the system might be wrong. It could be 2 compute nodes with 10 cores each for all we know.

Comment: I'm not so pessimistic as to believe that a person could mistake two nodes of a cluster for a workstation.  Occam's razor says there is a different problem.

Comment: omp_get_num_procs returns 10 so these are 10 cores for 1 actual CPU. It seems to ignore second CPU altogether. Hyperthreading is disabled in BIOS. OS is Windows Server 2012. I do not set OMP_NUM_THREADS